# Automatically create a spreadsheet for each cell from a selected range using a template sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have a simple question that I can't seem to solve. I just want to copy a template sheet for every selected cell from a range of cells and name each tab with their respective cell value. In this case the name will be just a date.
When I make my range selection and run my code, it only copies the first cell that is being selected from that range. What change should I make to my code?
TIA!

```
Sub copyAndRename()

Dim selectedcell As Long

    selectedcell = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
    Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = Format(selectedcell, "m-dd-yy")
    ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Value = selectedcell
    
    
    'Stay on the same sheet
    Sheets("Daily Averages").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You need a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy and Rename Worksheet

```vb
Sub CopyAndRename()

    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No visible workbooks open.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then
        MsgBox "Not a worksheet (" & ActiveSheet.Name & ").", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
        MsgBox "Not a range selected.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim lrg As Range
    Set lrg = Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, lws.Columns("A"))

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = lws.Parent
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Template")
    
    Dim dsh As Object, lCell As Range, lValue, dName As String
    
    For Each lCell In lrg.Cells
        lValue = lCell.Value
        If IsDate(lValue) Then
            dName = Format(lValue, "m-dd-yyy")
            On Error Resume Next
                Set dsh = wb.Sheets(dName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If dsh Is Nothing Then ' doesn't exist
                sws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
                With wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
                    .Name = dName
                    .Range("B6").Value = lValue
                End With
            Else ' already exists; do nothing
                Set dsh = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next lCell
        
    Application.Goto lws.Range("A1")
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Sub CreateAndRenameSheets()
    Dim selectedCell As Range
    Dim dailyAveragesSheet As Worksheet
    
    ' Set the reference to the "Daily Averages" sheet
    Set dailyAveragesSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Averages")
    
    ' Loop through each selected cell
    For Each selectedCell In Selection
        
            ' Copy the "Template" sheet
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
            
            ' Rename the copied sheet to the value of the selected cell
            ActiveSheet.Name = Format(selectedCell, "m-dd-yy")
            
            ' Put the selected cell value in range B6 of the copied sheet
            ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Value = selectedCell.Value
    Next selectedCell
    
    ' Go back to the "Daily Averages" sheet
    dailyAveragesSheet.Activate
    dailyAveragesSheet.Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```